# There exists a function $f: \Bbb R \mapsto \Bbb R$ such that $f^{(4)}(x)$ exists for all $x$ in $\Bbb R$ but is discontinuous at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Give an example of a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $f^{(4)}(x)=f’’’’(x)$ exists for all $x$ in $\Bbb R$ but is discontinuous at $x=0$. I tried it but I have no clue how to construct examples.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: Start here: write down what makes a function differentiable and what makes a function continuous.

Comment: @Lubin, $g'$ *dis*continuous.

Comment: Whoops, @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla — there I go again, misreading. I’ll delete that comment.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let 
$$g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lc}
x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & \mbox{ if } x \neq 0 \\
0& \mbox{ if } x=0 \end{array} \right.
$$

Then $g$ is differentiable everywhere, but $g'$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

\

Answer (score 0):

Let consider

$$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lc}
0 & \mbox{ if } x < 0 \\
x^4& \mbox{ if } x\ge0 \end{array} \right.$$